# Nova Laravel Unit Testing Expecting Return 201, But Return 403

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-nova, laravel-unit-test

I'm gonna make a Unit Testing for my resource.
Here my testing function below :

```
public function testCreateMyResource()
{
    $user = factory(\App\User::class)->states('admin')->create();
    $this->actingAs($user);
    $data = [
        'Field' => "Example",
    ];

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->postJson('/nova-api/my-resource?editing=true&editMode=create',$data);
    $response->assertStatus(201);
    $response->assertJson(['status' => true]);
    $response->assertJson(['message' => "Created!"]);

}
```

But it was return 403.
I expected to return 201 as I login normally to Nova dashboard and create new record in the form.
It seems like forbidden to access the route inside Testing Class.
Is there anyway to access the route ? Please any body help me to solve this.